# how to add script inside a php code?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I add script inside a php code? suppose i want to give an alert for a button click.. how can i do that??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can just echo all the HTML as normal:

```
<?php
   echo '<input type="button" onclick="alert(\'Clicky!\')"/>';
?>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
<?php
  echo"<script language='javascript'>

</script>
";
?>
```

Comment: So if my pages are generated via PHP and they have page-specific javascript I can just write it into the PHP like this and it will execute properly?

Answer (score 6):

You mean JavaScript?  Just output it like anything else in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <?php echo "alert('message');"; ?>
</script>
```

If want PHP to generate a custom message for the alert dialog, then basically you want to write your JavaScript as usual in the HTML, but insert PHP echo statements in the middle of your JavaScript where you want the messages, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('<?php echo $custom_message; ?>');
</script>
```

Or you could even do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var alertMsg = '<?php echo $custom_message; ?>';
  alert(alertMsg);
</script>
```

Basically, think about where in your JavaScript you want PHP to generate dynamic output and just put an echo statement there.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid escaping lot of characters:

```
   echo <<<MYSCRIPT

    ... script here...

    MYSCRIPT;
```

or just turn off php parsing for a while:

```
?>
...your script here
<?php
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use PHP's file_get_contents();

```
<?php

   $script = file_get_contents('javascriptFile.js');
   echo "<script>".$script."</script>";

?>
```

For more information on the function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to show a javascript alert when a button is clicked on a PHP generated page?

```
echo('<button type="button" onclick="alert(\'Alrt Text!\');">My Button</button>');
```

Would do that

Answer (score 1):

You can insert script to HTML like in any other (non-PHP) page, PHP processes it like any other code:

```
<button id="butt">
  → Click ME! ←
</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("butt").onclick = function () {
        alert("Message");
    }
</script>
```

---

You can use `onSOMETHING` attributes:

```
<button onclick="alert('Message')">Button</button>
```

---

To generate message in PHP, use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) function (it can convert to JavaScript everything that can be expressed in JSON — arrays, objects, strings, …):

```
<?php $message = "Your message variable"; ?>

<button onclick="alert(<?=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($message), ENT_QUOTES)?>)">Click me!</button>
```

---

If you generate code for `<script>` tags, do **NOT** use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) or similar function:

```
<?php $var = "Test string"; ?>

<button id="butt">Button</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("butt").onclick = function () {
        alert(<?=json_encode($var)?>);
    }
</script>
```

---

You can generate whole JavaScript files, not only JavaScript embedded into HTML. You still have to name them with `.php` extension (like `script.php`). Just send the correct header.

#### `script.php` – The JavaScript file

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/javascript"); /* This meant the file can be used in script tag */ ?>

<?php $var = "Message"; ?>

document.getElementById("butt").onclick = function () {
    alert(<?=json_encode($var)?>);
}
```

#### `index.html` – Example page that uses `script.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="butt">
            BUTTON
        </button>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way you add HTML tags. Echo it

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid accidentally including the same script twice is to implement a script management module in your templating system. The typical way to include a script is to use the SCRIPT tag in your HTML page.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="menu_1.0.17.js"></script>
```

An alternative in PHP would be to create a function called insertScript.

```
  <?php insertScript("menu.js") ?>
```

Comment: Whats the contents of `insertScript()`??

Answer (score 0):

To add javascript inside a PHP code you can do this

```
<?php    
echo "<script>alert('message');</script>";
?>
```

Better this

```
<?php
echo "<script src='myScript.js'></script>";
?>
```

And this for WordPress function.php file

```
<?php
$script= get_template_directory_uri() . '/myScript.js';
echo "<script src=".$script."></script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php file you can do something like this :

```
<? 
  //Your php code
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //Your javascript code
</script>

<?php //Your php code
```